# How do I change the transparency of the "selected" background without changing the transparency of the selected item itself?

Tags: wpf

Setting the opacity value changes both the background (good) and the selected item itself (bad).

```
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="LightSlateGray"/>
                    <!--<Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="Bd" Value="0.5"/>-->
                </Trigger>
                <MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                        <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightTextBrushKey}}"/>
                </MultiTrigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Comment: Why not just use a semi-transparent background, e.g. `#7F778899`?

Comment: It works nicely as a temp solution, but I was hoping for something a little more structured in case I wanted to do something fancier later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `LightSlateGray` is #778899.You can set just #7F778899 using `ARgb`.

Comment: Works fine as a temporary solution, but I was hoping for a more structured solution in case I wanted to do more later.

Comment: What you mean by `more structured solution`?

Comment: I'm _very_ new to WPF, and in my single week of learning how to build UIs and draw with WPF, the impression I got was that most things that can be separated out into more XAML tags should be.  I assumed there would be one XAML tag for setting a background `<Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>` (which there was) and another for setting the opacity separately, something like `<Setter Property="BackgroundOpacity" Value="0.5"/>`.  I'm trying to find whether there's an equivalent for the latter.

Comment: No, there is no `BackgroungOpacity` property.

Comment: I'm also not sure what you mean by "structured solution". Using a #AARRGGBB value is probably the easiest, and best way to do it.

Comment: @KevinDeLorey Mostly just hoping that there might be a separate tag for the background's opacity, but it seems there isn't.  Thanks, Hamlet

Answer (score 1):

You may set the `Opacity` of a SolidColorBrush used as the `Background` like this:

```
<Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd">
        <Setter.Value>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="LightSlateGray" Opacity="0.5"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Trigger>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `#AARRGGBB` value but if you insist on doing it with `Opacity` then you can try this:

```
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Grid>
                <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true"/>
                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
            </Grid>

            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="LightSlateGray"/>
                    <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="Bd" Value="0.5"/>
                </Trigger>
                <MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                        <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightTextBrushKey}}"/>
                </MultiTrigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```